Throwing unhandled error throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
`    // server/index.js
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Hello from Express!" });
  });

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
     console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
  });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});

npm start   

> react-node-app@1.0.0 start
> node server/index.js

Server listening on 3001
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1897:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1945:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:2037:7)
at Function.listen (C:\Users\srush\Desktop\react-node-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
at Object. (C:\Users\srush\Desktop\react-node-app\server\index.js:17:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 3001
}
Node.js v20.12.1your text
PS C:\Users\srush\Desktop\react-node-app> taskkill /f/im server.js
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/f/im'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.`

You are calling app.listen() twice. You can't listen on the same port a second time.

Same for me
export const store = { setup: false, count: 0 }

async function setup() {
    if (store.setup) {
        return console.log('Already settled up.');
    }

    store.setup = true;
    ...
    console.log(`hello`);

    const port = process.env.PORT || 8004
    app.listen(port)
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`)
}

console.log(`store`, store);

setup();

Console log is:
➜  react-vite-ssr-starter git:(master) ✗ bun dev
$ bun install && bun run start:dev
[0.10ms] ".env"
bun install v1.1.6 (e58d67b4)

Checked 547 installs across 617 packages (no changes) [13.00ms]
$ date; dotenvx run -- node ./server
Mon Apr 29 05:27:40 PM +03 2024
[dotenvx@0.35.1] injecting env (4) from .env
store { setup: false, count: 0 }
hello
Server running at http://localhost:8004
5:27:43 PM [vike][request(1)] HTTP request: /
store { setup: false, count: 0 }
tckimlikno 58
new Date() 2024-04-29T14:27:44.599Z
5:27:44 PM [vike][request(1)] HTTP response / 200
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::24678
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1872:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1920:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:2008:7)
    at Object.listen (file:///root/react-vite-ssr-starter/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DkOS1hkm.js:61166:27)
    at file:///root/react-vite-ssr-starter/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DkOS1hkm.js:65901:51
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.listen (file:///root/react-vite-ssr-starter/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DkOS1hkm.js:65901:22)
    at _createServer (file:///root/react-vite-ssr-starter/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DkOS1hkm.js:65129:17)
    at setup (/root/react-vite-ssr-starter/server/index.js:44:25) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 24678
}
hello
Server running at http://localhost:8004
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8004
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1872:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1920:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:2008:7)
    at Function.listen (/root/react-vite-ssr-starter/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
    at setup (/root/react-vite-ssr-starter/server/index.js:86:9)
Command exited with exit code 1: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/bin/node ./server
error: script "start:dev" exited with code 1
error: script "dev" exited with code 1

